# Getting result of SQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the result of a query with PHP but it is not working at the moment.
I have a class with a public method:

```
public static function getRoomTypeDiscountValue($id_product, $booking_length, $discount_type)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->executeS(
        'SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'htl_room_type_discount_rules`
        WHERE `id_product`='.(int) $id_product.' LIMIT 1'
    );
}
```

which results if i submit it using the web page and without **LIMIT 1** is:
[image]

Now i would retrieve the information contained in the percentage_value col

```
    $discount_percentage = HotelRoomTypeDiscountRuling::getRoomTypeDiscountValue($id_product, $numDaysInDuration, 1);
    $val=$discount_percentage['discount_percentage'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$val');</script>";
```

But the alert has no content.
If i do

```
    $discount_percentage = HotelRoomTypeDiscountRuling::getRoomTypeDiscountValue($id_product, $numDaysInDuration, 1);
    $val=count($discount_percentage);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$val');</script>";
```

it shows me correctly the number of rows of the results, so if I remove the **LIMIT 1** i get 2 in the alert otherwise i get 1.

So I assume that the query is working but i'm struggling to access to the data in the variable

Comment: Whenever you're in doubt, `var_dump` the variable that's giving you trouble and take a look what's really inside.

Comment: its probably an array .. try `$discount_percentage[0]['discount_percentage']`

Comment: use `var_dump($discount_percentage)` of even `gettype($discount_percentage)` to understand the type and the data of your variable

Comment: Thanks for the hints:
The type is an array and here the var_dump:

array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id_discount_rule"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_product"]=> string(2) "14" ["booking_length"]=> string(1) "3" ["discount_type"]=> string(1) "1" ["fixed_value"]=> string(1) "0" ["percentage_value"]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(6) { ["id_discount_rule"]=> string(1) "2" ["id_product"]=> string(2) "14" ["booking_length"]=> string(1) "5" ["discount_type"]=> string(1) "1" ["fixed_value"]=> string(1) "0" ["percentage_value"]=> string(2) "15" } }

Comment: So you have an array with two elements. It's up to you to choose which element's `discount_percentage` you wish to use. Refer to @snitch182's comment for the right access syntax. Also, for future reference, please add new information by editing the question, it's more readable than the comments.